# Rspec Mocking: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, mocking, rspec

I'm new to Rspec and trying to set up a test for a User Profile. Profile belongs_to User.

Now, I have an API integration with a third party site that works through the User Model, but some of the information for that API link is contained in Profile, so I have an "after_update" filter on Profile that tells the parent user to save, which triggers an update of the API.

I'm trying to write a test for this, and I'm getting an ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch. The reason is I'm using a mock user, but I'm trying to test that when Profile is updated it sends :save to User. Plus, the User model has an email confirmation process and the afformentioned API calls in it's create process, so it really isn't ideal to actually create a user just to test this out.

Here's my test:

```
it "should save the parent user object after it is saved" do
    user = double('user', :save => true )
    profile = Profile.create( :first_name => 'John', :last_name => 'Doe' )
    profile.user = user

    user.should_receive(:save)
end
```

So, clearly the ActiveRecord error is being caused by trying to associate a mock user with a profile that expects a real user to be associated.

My question is, how do you avoid this kind of problem in writing rails tests? All I want this test to do is make sure Profile calls :save on it's parent User. Is there a smarter way to do this, or a workaround for the ActiveRecord error?

Thanks!

Comment: Personally I would use something like factory_girl to craft an already-confirmed User object and then set the `save` expectation on that. Are you not able to fake a confirmed user without going through the e-mail process? That sets off some alarms with regard to the code design.

Comment: Well, your suggestion ended up being the way I had to go. I was able to isolate the API I didn't want called by telling the controller not to trigger that call in the test environment, so that let me work with Factory objects as expected. However, I had to turn the API actions back on to test integrations, so in the end I just abandoned this approach and am allowing the sandbox environment for the API get full of junk data which I have to clear out periodically. Not what I would have preferred, but it lets me test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the only way I was able to get around this problem was to use a Factory user instead of a mock. That's frustrating, but when testing the callbacks between two ActiveRecord models you have to use the real models or else save calls will fail, the lifecycle won't happen, and the callbacks can't be tested.

Comment: Shouldn't callbacks be tested in the relevant model spec?

Comment: you saved my life

Answer (score 13):

You should be able to use a `mock_model` for this:

```
it "should save the parent user object after it is saved" do
  user = mock_model(User)
  user.should_receive(:save).and_return(true)
  profile = Profile.create( :first_name => 'John', :last_name => 'Doe' )
  profile.user = user
end
```

Comment: note that as of rspec v3, `mock_model` has been extracted into a separate gem `rspec-activemodel-mocks`  see https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-2/docs/upgrade#extract-stub-model