# Rails testing with RSpec double: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, activerecord, rspec

I am new to RSpec (not very experienced yet with RoR neither!)

I am working on a web app where I have a Course model. To create a new Course I need to use Teacher and Student objects.

I want to create a test on the Course model and for that I am trying to use instance_double to mock Teacher and Student. Here is my code

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Course, type: :model do
  it 'can be created' do
    # creating the teacher
    john = instance_double(Teacher)
    allow(john).to receive(:save).and_return(true)
    allow(john).to receive(:id).and_return(1)

    # creating the student
    francois = instance_double(Student)
    allow(francois).to receive(:save).and_return(true)
    allow(francois).to receive(:id).and_return(1)

    # creating the course
    testCourse = Course.new(teacher: john, student: francois, class_language: "EN")

    # testing the course
    expect(testCourse).to be_valid
  end
end
```

I get the next failure from RSpec

```
 1) Course can be created
     Failure/Error: testCourse = Course.new(teacher: john, student: francois, class_language: "EN")
     
     ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
       Teacher(#70253947615480) expected, got #<Double Teacher(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, first_name: string, last_name: string, about: text, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)> which is an instance of RSpec::Mocks::Double(#70253946301600)
     # ./spec/models/course_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.02549 seconds (files took 2.87 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

My understanding is that ActiveRecord error is being caused by trying to associate a instance_double teacher and user with a course that expects a "real" teacher and student to be associated.

I have been trying many different ways, faking ID (see my code), or calling the models ([see article here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/verifying-doubles/using-an-instance-double)) themselves with

```
require 'student'
require 'teacher'
```

I saw [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882741/rspec-mocking-activerecordassociationtypemismatch) about similar issue, so I used non-deprecated syntax and it still doesn't work.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Why not use real Student and Teacher? If you're worried about inserting two DB records in this test, you can use something like transactional fixtures.

Comment: Thanks Sergio, I did it as you proposed and it works

Answer (score 0):

If you are still in the early stages of building your test suite, I would suggest implementing factories, this way you can create valid records by just calling them, you can read more about them in this article:
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/why-factories
, then create a factory for each of your models, and when you write your specs for your Course model, do this before your specs:

```
let(:teacher) { create(:teacher) }
let(:student) { create(:student) }
let(:course)  { build(:course, teacher: teacher, student: student) }
```

and then write your spec like so:

```
it 'creates course successfully' do
  expect(course.save).to be true
end
```

Comment: Hi Farah, thanks for your help, I am not yet knowledgeable on factories! I will read the article you shared! On the short term I solved my issue with Sergio proposal

Answer (score 0):

I would really discourage you from using `expect(...).to be_valid` in your specs. This aweful carpet bombing approach propularized by the Rails Tutorial Book does very little to descibe the *behavior* of your validations and instead actually just tests the test setup itself. IE you're really just testing your mocks more then your actual application!

```
RSpec.describe Course, type: :model do
  let(:course){ Course.new }

  it 'requires a teacher' do
    course.valid?
    expect(course.errors.details[:teacher]).to include { error: :blank }
    course.teacher_id = 1 # doesn't actually have to exist
    course.valid?
    expect(course.errors.details[:teacher]).to_not include { error: :blank }
  end
end
```

This is somewhat tedious to write and can also be done with the shoulda-matchers gem.

```
RSpec.describe Course, type: :model do
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:teacher) }
end
```

Comment: yeah, I either use something like shoulda-matchers or don't test built-in validations at all (by providing input that always satisfies them)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I like to do feature or request specs with invalid input to test the validations and the whole stack at once. You just have to weigh the added value against how long it takes to run the specs.